# How to Run Laravel Scheduler on Google Cloud

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to run Laravel Scheduler in Google Cloud.

> In my command, I have this

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class ChangeRole extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'command:update';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'This Changes Stuffs';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        //
        $users = User::where('trialExpires', '<=', Carbon::now())->get();
        foreach ($users as $user) {
        $user->type= 'subscriber';
        $user->save();
        }

    }
}
```

> I have done this in my Kernel

```
protected $commands = [
    //
    'App\Console\Commands\ChangeRole',
];

/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
     $schedule->command('command:update')
              ->daily();
}
```

> In my cron.yaml file

```
cron:
- description: "daily job"
  url: '* * * * * cd /project_id && php artisan command:update >> /dev/null 2>&1'
  schedule: every 24 hours
  retry_parameters:
    min_backoff_seconds: 2.5
    max_doublings: 5
  timezone: Europe/Madrid
```

When I ran `gcloud app deploy cron.yaml`
I got this error

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) An error occurred while parsing file: [C:\xampp1\newlibri\cron.yaml]
>   Unable to assign value '* * * * * cd /starlit-advice-260914 && php artisan command:update >> /dev/null 2>&1' to attribute 'url':
>   Value '* * * * * cd /starlit-advice-260914 && php artisan command:update >> /dev/null 2>&1' for url does not match expression '^(?:^/.*$)$'
>     in "C:\xampp1\newlibri\cron.yaml", line 3, column 8

I don't know what I did wrong.

When I run PHP artisan command:update. The scheduler work just fine. But I am unable to replicate on Google Cloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to fix the error.

I have to set the URL to a get request in my application.

```
cron:
- description: "daily summary job"
  url: /api/checksub
  schedule: every 24 hours
  retry_parameters:
    min_backoff_seconds: 2.5
    max_doublings: 5
  timezone: Europe/Madrid
```

In my controller, I have this

```
  public function checksub() {
    $users = User::where('trialExpires', '<=', Carbon::now())->update(['role'=> 'subscriber']);
      ));
}
```

It doesn't need to setup Laravel Scheduler. Just call the get result of the URL

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the default implementation for these scheduler tasks. Basically what you do is setup a CRON task which runs the scheduler function every minute, and let the PHP code decide whether to run particular tasks.

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

This will run your `app\Console\Kernel.php::schedule()` function every minute, in which you can then define your tasks like:

```php
// Example function which removes users older than a year.
$schedule->call(function () {
    User::query()
    ->where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subYear())
    ->delete();
})->hourly();
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling